# Functions.php in child theme that loads CSS file breaks website

Tags: functions, css, child-theme

I created a child theme and created a functions.php file in the child theme directory that also has the required style.css file and a seperate custom CSS file that I want to load. This is the code I use:

```
<? php 

add_action('wp_head', 'add_landing_css');
function add_landing_css() {

wp_enqueue_style('landing_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/landing.css','screen');
}
?>
```

When I add this code to functions.php every page on my website is blank. It doesn't load anything. When I delete functions.php file my website works as normal. I use a theme called Modest from elegant themes.

Comment: Turn on debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the syntax error is this typo:

```
<? php
```

It should be

```
<?php
```

Secondly, you should use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook instead of the `wp_head` hook.

Check out the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) for more info on the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) hook.